# Normalizing and plot time series data in SPSS

Tags: time-series, spss

I have a dataset in long format that looks like this:

```
Year ID Mean_Income 
2008 1  15042
2009 1  15205
2010 1  15800
2011 1  16443
2008 1  17324
2009 1  17844
2010 2  18011
2011 2  18099
2008 3  16333
2009 3  16554
2010 3  16831
2011 3  16900
.
.
.
2008 150  14998
2009 150  15200
2010 150  15411
2011 150  15500
```

I'd like to normalize data so that for the first year (2008) the value for income is 100 for every ID, and so that the value for every year thereafter increases in a corresponding share to the actual increase in income. Something like this:

```
Year ID Mean_Income Normalized_inc
2008 1  15042       100
2009 1  15205       101
2010 1  15800       104 
2011 1  16443       108
```

I hope I made myself clear enough. I've tried transforming values into Z-scores but it doesn't quite solve my problem - I want to see the trend over time from a common starting level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might add a new variable with the 2008 value for each ID, and then use it for normalization by dividing every subsequent value by that first one:

```
if year=2008 Mean_Income_2008=Mean_Income.
aggregate /out=* mode=addvariables overwrite=yes 
     /break=ID /Mean_Income_2008=max(Mean_Income_2008).

*now you have the 2008 value in each line, 
 the following is one possibility of using it for normalization.

compute Normalized_inc=Mean_Income/Mean_Income_2008*100.
```